# iPhone - Converting *NSMutableString to UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

In my app, I want to show a barcode image. The barcode generation happens at the web server. So, the iOS client calls a web service to get the binary blob representation of the barcode image.

On the iOS side, I am receiving the byte[] in a NSMutableString property in my response class. This value is base x64 encoded. This is what I am doing to convert it into a UIImage which I will then show inside a UIImageViewer:

```
    NSData *imageData = [response.barcodeImage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Image data%@", imageData);
    UIImage *testImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"Image %@", testImage);
```

The value of first NSLog is something like this:

```
Image data<6956424f 5277304b 47676f41 4141414e 53556845 55674141 41693041 41414164 43415941 4141426d 44467a32 41414141 41584e53 52304941 72733463 36514141 4141526e
```

But second NSLog output is: Image (null)

What is it that I am doing wrong/missing here?

Thanks

Comment: If `response.barcodeImage` represents the base64 encoded image data, where you do attempt to convert the base64 encoded string into data? The code you posted makes no such attempt.

Comment: @rmaddy: This is where I am trying to do that:     NSData *imageData = [response.barcodeImage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: That doesn't do base64 conversion.

Comment: @ezile from where you got the idea that this method does Base64 decoding? **Did you even read its documentation?** Did you even **think** about it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you’re skipping a step—you’ll need to undo the base-64 encoding before UIImage `-initWithData:` can understand it. As of iOS 7, NSData has a utility method to do that for you:

```
imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:response.barcodeImage options:0];
```

If you need to support older versions of iOS, a quick web search will turn up lots of sample code to build your own base-64 decoding with.

Comment: Isn't this statement will do that?

NSData *imageData = [response.barcodeImage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: @ezile - Nope, not even close.

Comment: Also, I am not building this for IOS 7 so it gives me the error that initWithBase64EncodedString function not found. Is there any other utility/way to do that?

Comment: @ezile yes, google for "Objective-C base64 library".